# How can I use PowerShell to find a website's certificate?

Tags: powershell, certificate, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use PowerShell to query a website and see what SSL certificate (name) it is using for HTTPS bindings. Then I would like to trace back to see what CA issued the cert.

I am having trouble querying the website to find out what SSL certificate is bound. The IIS 7.5 GUI shows a friendly name.

After I get the websites SSL certificate the plan is to use PowerShell to search the Certificate stores by `FriendlyName` (or thumbprint, or some other value).

Here is what I have so far:

- Query store for cert info:

  ```
  get-childitem cert:\LocalMachine\my | ft issuer, subject, notafter, FriendlyName
  ```
- check for active bindings

  ```
  get-itemproperty 'IIS:\Sites\(SITENAME)' -name bindings
  ```

I'm not sure where this information is stored, and I have no luck searching for it with PowerShell, in the `web.config` and `applicationhost.config`. Google searching has not been helpful so far.

Any info, links to information, or documentation on how certs are handled / stored in IIS is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the site SSL binding check out: `IIS:\SslBinding`

You can get the binding port like this:

```
dir IIS:\SslBindings | ? {$_.Port -eq 1443} | Select *
```

The `Thumbprint` and `Store` properties will be of interest.

You can get the actual cert using:

```
get-item cert:\LocalMachine\$theStore\$theThumbprint
```

e.g.

```
get-item cert:\LocalMachine\My\29F025A78F537D931A8CF05B00EB81DB84160CF3 | select *
```

Comment: @colo_joe Np, did this answer your question?